# Can't seem to open files with a file manager

Tags: i3, nautilus

I've been trying to use i3 instead of GNOME, but I still use Nautilus as my file manager. The problem is, when I try to open a file, like a video, a text file, or virtually anything else, nothing happens, either when I double-click on it, or right-click and select "open with Program X."

Everything works fine when I'm in GNOME. Also, if I run gnome-session once per session, everything works fine after that.

Strangely, I can open any file from Nautilus when I have the appropriate program already open, e.g., Totem (Videos), gedit, etc.

What's strange is that this also affects any other GTK file manager I try to use (nemo, pantheon-files, you name it).

I'm on the latest Arch Linux, BTW (Antergos, actually).

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: Nope. `--no-desktop` doesn't seem to be a documented option (not listed in `nautilus --help`, but I tried it anyway, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which player is associated with that video files in Nautilus, and in Gnome? Can probably be found somewhere in the file's context menu, file properties.

Comment: @Murphy, Videos. (Totem). Like I said, it works fine when I have Totem already open.

Comment: In this case check the options associated with the call in Nautilus.

Comment: What options? What call?

Comment: see if you get the same behavior when opening these files with `xdg-open` on the commandline.

Comment: xdg-open works.

Comment: In the 'open with...' have you provided the full path of the commands?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I see an "open with" tab in file properties, but there is no way to set paths, only select an application from a list. The default application is selected. I haven't changed any of the settings from their defaults. And everything works fine, so long as either 1) I'm in GNOME, 2) I have a GNOME session running, or 3) I have the program that plays the files already open. So somehow GNOME is setting some variable somewhere that allows files to open, and without this they don't open.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (I don't use gnome), but possibly nautilus/gnome uses `gvfs-open`, not `xdg-open`? I'm not massively sure what testing this will tell you, but perhaps it might help elucidate…

Comment: We're getting warmer. `xdg-open` is deprecated, but replaced with `gio open`. This command doesn't work as expected. But it doesn't give an error, either, and there doesn't seem to be a `--verbose` or `--debug` option.

Comment: Have you tried launching `nautilus` from the command line, and checking if it generates helpful error messages when it fails to open a file? If it turns out that `nautilus` is always generating many messages, redirect output to a file, and check/search/scan that. If that's not helpful, try running `nautilus` with `strace`.

Comment: Nautilus doesn't show any messages when it fails to open a file. Strace shows a ton of messages about everything, but I can't pick through it to find anything useful. It's probably using `gio open` which isn't working.

Comment: @Jonathan did you ever get this working?

Comment: Nope, I had to reinstall my OS, basically.